# Front page Featured Section

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have a website where users register their projects for a certain event. I'd like to highlight certain projects on certain days on the front page.

What's the easiest way to add a "Featured Section" that accomplishes this? I know I can go through and make the post sticky but that seems tedious. Is it possible to use Views to do this or is there some other module available?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the 'certain days' part of that is a manual process, this sounds like a perfect fit for the [Nodequeue](http://drupal.org/project/nodequeue) module, which integrates very nicely with views (and even automatically creates one for each separate queue). So, in your example, you might create a Nodequeue called 'Featured Section', that accepts nodes of a certain type, and then you can quickly add content to that. A view on the home page would pull in only nodes in that queue.

Comment: This would just be a more fancy than using sticky, but in reality the process would be the same, only you get the extra overhead of a new module.

Comment: Indeed, but the question was asking for a less tedious solution than Drupal core's notion of sticky that made possible the use of views. Nodequeue adds ajax callbacks for adding/removing content to a queue and simple administrative lists of all content in a queue, so not only is it more fancy, but much more useable and flexible.

Comment: I like the nodequeue as well. Suppose you want to have control over the ordering. Suppose your view is sorted by reverse cron and you have an item that you want at the top, a nodequeue will allow this.

Comment: do you know how i can combine nodequeue with jquery? Thanks for the help.

Comment: It depends on what you're looking to do with jQuery. Nodequeue already provides ajax add/remove links that are built using jQuery (since this is Drupal's js library).

Answer (score 1):

Modules for events: [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) (for displaying in front page) + [CCK](http://drupal.org/project/cck) (for featured and date fields) + [calendar](http://drupal.org/project/calendar) (for showing events as calendar (page or block))

Answer (score 0):

You could use Views to do this, and add a CCK field (or taxonomy if you like) to flag a node as 'Featured'.